# How to save the email and name fields in the Django deafult User table

Tags: python, django, forms, save

I want to save the email and name fields in django default table called UserSignup
my models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
class UserSignup(models.Model):
    mailid      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

my views.py is:

```
from django import views
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from Deals.signup.forms import signup
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse

def usersignup(request,form_class=signup):

   form = form_class()
   print form
   if form.is_valid():  
       mail= UserSignup(mailid=request.POST['mailid'])
       mail.save()
       name= UserSignup(name=request.POST['name'])
       name.save()
  else:
       form = form_class()    
  return render_to_response('signup/registration_form.html',{'form':form})
```

and forms.py is

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Deals.signup.models import *
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class signup(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(),
                         label=_("Email address:"))

    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$',
                            max_length=30,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(),
                            label=_("Name:"))

def save(self,request,update):

    name =  self.cleaned_data['name']
    name.save()
    email =  self.cleaned_data['email']
    email.save()
```

Please help me in saving my forms input in database

Answer (score 0):

Check the Django documentation properly http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Just change your code in views.py.

```
def usersignup(request,form_class=signup):

    if request.method == 'POST': #If its a form submission, the method is POST
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  
             newuser = form.save()
    else: #Else display the form 
        form = form_class()    

    return render_to_response('signup/registration_form.html',{'form':form})
```

The 'save' function in your forms file is incorrect and is not needed.

On a side note, your "UserSignup" is not a default User Table. That would be the user model provided by Django. And that already has the fields that you are creating in UserSignup. Why don't you use that feature of Django?

Comment: `if request.method = 'POST':` should probably use the comparison `==` instead.

Comment: @kriegar - Yep, fixed now. I wrote the code from top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to save the model elements in the form in one time.

```
def save(self):
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(name = self.cleaned_data['name'],
                                        email = self.cleaned_data['email'])
return new_user
```